# PDO/PHP query not returning results of array

Tags: php, pdo

I have the below code which seems be fine except that it will not echo the results. If I change the echo statement to just read echo $pointrow, then it will return "array". So I wrote it the way I did below and now there is nothing at all on the page. Not sure what I am doing wrong. There is indeed a column in the points table called points.

```
<?php
$pointresults = $dbh->prepare("SELECT
wp_users.ID,
points.points
FROM wp_users
LEFT JOIN points on points.ID = wp_users.ID
WHERE (wp_users.ID = $user_ID)");

$pointresults->bindParam(':wp_users.ID', $user_ID, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$pointresults->bindParam(':points.ID', $ID, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$pointresults->execute();
$pointrow = $pointresults->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<?php echo $pointrow[0]['points'] ?>
```

Comment: Do you just want the first row?

Comment: I only have one record in the db currently, but yes, I just want the row that corresponds with the user ID who we are trying to lookup their score for.

Comment: I see that you've figured out your problem but if you only want one row then you can use `fetch` instead of `fetchAll`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
<?php
$pointresults = $dbh->prepare("SELECT
wp_users.ID,
points.points
FROM wp_users
LEFT JOIN points on points.ID = wp_users.ID
WHERE (wp_users.ID = :user_ID)");

$pointresults->bindParam(':user_ID', $user_ID, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$pointresults->execute();
$pointrow = $pointresults->fetchAll();
?>

<?php echo $pointrow[0]['points'] ?>
```

Comment: Tried that--just throws the error: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined. I think the code I have is right except for the echo code?

Comment: It's strange. I often used PDO. Could you add on just after the lwslast echo 2 more instructions - just to be sure: `echo '<br/>; var_dump($user_ID);`

Comment: I just figured it out. Silly...there was no value in the column points.